# Lines on scroll-bar CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I know in `webkit` it is possible to style the scroll bar using the `::-webkit-scrollbar` properties but is it possible to have lines on the scroll bar? If so how?

[image]

In chrome when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and type something lines appear on the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a custom scrollbar using `::-webkit-scroolbar` then use `linear-gradient` as the background of `::scrollbar-track`.

Here I wrote a demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gppBzX